# How to replace tooltip label in altair?

Tags: altair

I have a large dataset with coded column names. I made a dictionary with corresponding labels that explain the field, as such

```
codes = {
    "Q1r1" : "first", 
    "Q1r2" : "second", 
    "Q1r3" : "third", 
    "Q1r4" : "etc...", 
    }
```

So now I would like to replace field names in tooltip with respective labels from `codes.get()`, but cannot figure out how to refer to outside dict from either `.encode()` or any `.transforms`.

Just to be clear: if the field referenced in below code is `"Q1r1"`, I would like to have it shown in tooltip as `"first"` instead.

```
alt.Chart(df).mark_point().encode(
    x='x:Q',
    y='y:Q',
    size='z:Q',
    color=alt.Color('group:N'),
    tooltip=['group:N', 'field:N']
)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about mapping the group names first:

```py
df['group_mapped'] = df['group'].map(codes)
alt.Chart(df).mark_point().encode(
    x='x:Q',
    y='y:Q',
    size='z:Q',
    color=alt.Color('group:N'),
    tooltip=['group_mapped:N', 'field:N']
)
```

Comment: yes, this would work, but i would not like to change the dataframe in any way, as this would break things elsewhere. another option would be to create a slice with replaced values just for visualising - but i was hoping that perhaps there is a way to do the mapping in altair.

Comment: then take a copy first:

```python
df_plot = df.copy()
df_plot['group_mapped'] = df_plot['group'].map(codes)
alt.Chart(df_plot).mark_point().encode(
    x='x:Q',
    y='y:Q',
    size='z:Q',
    color=alt.Color('group:N'),
    tooltip=['group_mapped:N', 'field:N']
)
```